# AngularJS change body width according to page innerWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would like to make my page scrollable.

Therfore i need to add width element on top of the body.

if i will do width:100%; the scroller will never show, so i'm looking for a simple solution to sample to page width and set it to the body when it changes.

i have two issues:

1. i can't make it work.
2. the watch only fires when the app loaded and not every time the window width changes.

This is the code i used:

```
   $scope.$watch(function(){
            return $window.innerWidth;
        }, function(value) {
            $scope.cols = value;
            var width = value +'px !important';

            $('body').css("width", width);
        });
```

Comment: side comment - consider using a throttle/debounce with resize events

Comment: have you set `overflow` property in css?

Comment: @charlietfl yes i did, but i need to set a fixed width for that and the current width is 100% so the scroller is never sown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a directive like this, change your `<body>` to become `<body resize-body>`and add this directive to your app.

```
app.directive('resizeBody', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.onResize = function() {
                $(elem).width($window.innerWidth);
            }
            scope.onResize();

            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                scope.onResize();
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Now, everytime you resize your window the body element will have window innerWidth.
I didn't test it!

Comment: Thanks but i don't want it to be 100%, i can set it 100% at the begning and the resize doesn't change anything cause it will always set it to 100% i want to be able to change it's width with px, so the scroll will show

Comment: with that directive you can do everything you want. How much wide should it be?

Comment: should be automatically adjusted to the screen width, and every time somone changes it it should set the body automatically to that size.

Comment: I updated it to set the width as the $window.innerWidth

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var w = angular.element($window);
w.bind('resize', function () {
         // set dimensions here with w.width() and w.height()
         $('body').css("width", w.width()); // in your case
    });
```

Comment: for some reason the body is not getting the width property, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to the `resize` event of the window. You **cannot watch a DOM attribute** because changes to it do not initiate an Angular digest. A solution that updates a `$rootScope` property (but can easilly be tweaked to update anything else) is:

```
app.run(['$window', '$rootScope', function($window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        });
    });
}]);
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9hgao61/

Comment: how can i set the new size to the page body?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `$('body').css("width", window.innerWidth);` in the `$apply` body?